# Trying to send a json object to an api and am getting a failed to decode error

Tags: json, api

Here is the curl command I am using.  Any help is appreciated

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:4000/create -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d '"{data1":"'"$data1"'", "data2": "'"$data2"'", "data3": "'"$data3"'", "data4": "'"$data4"'"}'
```

This is what I get back from the api.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Extra data: line 1 column 10 (char 9)</p>
```

I have tried changing the way the single and double quotes are and stared at this for hours.  I expected the api to give back a json object based on the $data variables

Comment: Did you tried with some REST client like Postman or Talend?

Comment: Could you show us the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your JSON data format. Here's the corrected curl command:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:4000/create -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d '{"data1":"'"$data1"'", "data2": "'"$data2"'", "data3": "'"$data3"'", "data4": "'"$data4"'"}'
```

This should fix the issue with the JSON decoding error, but also make sure the values of $data1, $data2, ... variables are properly formatted and don't contain any special characters that could break the JSON structure.

One suggestion I have is to double check this by:

1. `echo` the output:

   ```bash
   echo '{"data1":"'"$data1"'", "data2": "'"$data2"'", "data3": "'"$data3"'", "data4": "'"$data4"'"}'
   ```
2. Pass the result to `JSON.stringify`. This should work and not throw a syntax error.